# Convert string to long jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to convert my field which is String (but contains long value) to Long in jasper reports. 
So I set up field value as a String (cause I get it from java) and in detail I am trying to convert this string to long. I set expression in text field into `new java.lang.Long.valueOf($F{value})`
however it doesnt work. Try multiple times with different ways.

That's kind of wierd because from Long I easly cast to Date using same way: `new Date($F{measureTimestamp})` and it works perfectly.

Could you please tell me how to cast String to Long into JasperReports?

Comment: `java.lang.Long.valueOf` is a static method, you can't put `new` in front of it (even if it weren't a static method anyway). Just remove `new`

Comment: As I said before I tried with multiple ways however it still not working. I tried also with java.lang.Long.valueOf :(

Comment: Then you need to post the exact errors that your system is reporting.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele it shows that I can not cast String to Long.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,99"`

Comment: Baiscly my value field is a string in jasper reports and I am trying to put it into linear chart. There I create an expression `java.lang.Double.valueOf($F{value})`

Comment: Then the problem is your input... It should work if you pass `0.99`. If you need to use the comma as decimal delimiter, then you should rather use a `java.text.DecimalFormat` (`parse`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170276/discussion-between-tom-and-ernest-kiwele).